# Laptop battery does not charge

Tags: laptop, battery

I bought a faulty LG R500 laptop and I repaired it.

However, the laptop battery does not charge. Therefore, I am unable to use the laptop when it is not plugged in.

In Linux Mint, a software shows me informations about the battery and it told me the capacity of the battery is 100%, but there is no power in it. I think the battery could be good since when I get an old battery, the capacity is likely to be less than 50%.

Here is a screenshot of the informations given by the software:

[image: http://sdz-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/upload/batterie.png]

What is odd is that this software indicate the battery is in discharge.

Is this battery faulty?

Is there a way to repair it?

Comment: What exactly was wrong and what did you do to repair it?  Long shot here but you should check to see if there are any BIOS updates you can install.

Comment: The graphics card was broken and I had to reflow it. I will check for any BIOS update.

Answer (score 0):

Since the voltage reads as zero, I'd say it is broken.  If it is removable, it may have just tripped its safety circuit.  Remove it and see if you can measure the terminal voltage and if it is zero, you may be able to apply the correct voltage with a bench power supply for a moment to revive it.